# Accessing Ninject WhereTargetHas attribute property values

Tags: c#, ninject

I am using Ninject to provide DI for a number of classes in a web project, some of these are database repositories that use a common sql connection factory class that is constructed with the connection string name being passed into the constructor.

I have this working with the following code but the code to get the connection string name from the target attribute is troubling me, can anyone suggest a more elegant solution?

When instatiating a IHeaderServiceRepository class, Ninject injects an instance of IConnectionFactory - when it does this it uses the ToMethod on the binding. This method gets the custom attributes of the target (of the correct attribute type) and uses it's connection string name to pass into the created type.

What I was expecting was to be able to access the custom attributes on the target via the Ninject Request object but I don't seem to be able to find it.

Can someone either tell me how I can do that or point out a better way of doing all this?

Ninject binding:

```
kernel.Bind<IHeaderServiceRepository>().To<HeaderServiceRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IConnectionFactory>().ToMethod(
            ctr =>
            {
                var customAttribute = ctr.Request.Target.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                       .OfType<ConnectionStringAttr>().FirstOrDefault();
                var connectionString = customAttribute != null ?
                                    customAttribute.ConnectionStringName : string.Empty;
                return new ConnectionFactoryBase(connectionString);
            }).WhenTargetHas<ConnectionStringAttr>().InRequestScope();
```

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class ConnectionStringAttr : Attribute
{
    public string ConnectionStringName { get; private set; }

    public ConnectionStringAttr(string connectionStringName)
    {
        this.ConnectionStringName = connectionStringName;
    }
}
```

Repository code:

```
public class HeaderServiceRepository : IHeaderServiceRepository
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    private readonly StoredProcedureHelper storedProcedureHelper;
    private readonly IConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public HeaderServiceRepository([ConnectionStringAttr("CONNECTION_STRING_NAME")] IConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this.log = logger;
        this.storedProcedureHelper = new StoredProcedureHelper(this.connectionFactory, this.log);
    }
```

Many thanks, Steve